# Плагин Ajax Load More конфликтует с Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

На Wordpress - мои посты выводятся через плагин Ajax Load More. И посты не реагируют на событие click();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on("click", ".класс-постов", function(e) {
  console.log("пост clicked");
});
```

Comment: Помогло, ты лучший)

Comment: @Dreamer Важно, чтобы Вы знали *почему* помогло.

Comment: из за jQuery не работало?

Comment: @Dreamer Нет. Вы делали вот так `$(".класс-постов").click(function(e) {...});`, то есть прикрепляли обработчики только к существующим на данный момент постам.